# После смены БД в Django с SQLite на PostgreSQL не проходит часть тест кейсов

Tags: python, django, postgresql, юнит-тесты

Прошу помощи. Есть работающий проект на Django, использовалась БД SQLite, с ней же были написаны TestCase, все проходили как нужно. Сменил БД на PostgreSQL и тесты начали падать с исключениями.

1. Тесты проходят всегда по разному - в первый раз после настройки новой БД упали почти все, но при этом при запуске отдельных тестов они могли успешно проходить.
2. В текущей ситуации при запуске всех тестов `python3 manage.py test` падает с исключениями только один тестовый модуль, но при этом запуск отдельного TestCase из этого модуля **может пройти**, но чаще падает с исключением.
3. При тестировании руками через браузер все кейсы проходят успешно, никаких ошибок не возникает.
4. Код до и после смены БД не изменялся.

```py
settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'TEST': {
            'TEMPLATE': 'test_db',
        }
    }
}

test_views.py # код одного из падающих тестов

class TestCoreViews(TestCase):
    number_of_persons = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # создает первого шаблонного Person
        # остальные со случайными данными
        person = get_test_person() 
        person.save()
        number_of_persons = 1
        for person in mim_do_persons(10, True): # собственный генератор экземпляров для БД, используется и в других тестах, которые проходят
            person.save()
            number_of_persons += 1
        cls.number_of_persons = number_of_persons
        test_user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='test')
        test_user.save()

    def login_test_user(self): # функция аутентификации для удобства, представления обязательно ее требуют
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')

    def test_url_exist(self): # непосредственно тест
        self.login_test_user() 
        for number in range(1, self.number_of_persons+1):
            response = self.client.get(f'/core/person/{number}/') # вот здесь тест падает на первой же итерации
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Само исключение:

```
response = self.client.get(f'/core/person/{number}/')
...
core.models.Person.DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
```

У меня очень большое подозрение, что django тут не причем, а что то не так с POstgreSQL, но не удается найти какой либо информации что вообще может быть не так. Единственное что более менее подходило под мою ситуацию - выполнение авторизации поверх уже выполненной, но `SetUpTestData` сбрасывает БД перед каждым тестом, а перестраховка в виде `self.client.logout()` не дает никакого результата. И повторюсь - по какой то странной логике тесты **иногда проходят**.

Сам PostgreSQL настраивал: для юзера БД и создана отдельная тестовая БД, и даны привелегии на создание новых БД (`alter role username createdb`).

Comment: модели прописывали? миграции делали?

Comment: Конечно прописывал, приложение полностью рабочее - только честы проходят через раз. Миграции выполнялись при подключении новой ДБ, но для тестовой базы оно и не должно требоваться - для них отдельная база с нуля собирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему.

Тестирование с обращением к записям по url формата `f'core/person/{id}/'` строилось из предположения что на каждый тест создается новая (чистая/пустая) база данных, и обращение к первому созданному объекту возможно по его id==1 (`'core/person/1/'`). И в sqlite это действительно работало.

При запуске ВСЕХ тестов с PSQL база действительно отчищается, но не "в ноль" - со второго TestCase и далее БД вычищает предыдущие записи, но при этом делает недоступными для записи ранее использованные id. Т.е. на последних тестах первый созданный и записанный экзепляр может получить id, к примеру, 14. И попытка обратиться к к нему по id=1 падает с исключением `DoesNotExist`. Решается сохранением id первого созданного элемента атрибутом класса, в `def SetUp(self)`, и применением его вместо id=1 (а как `Person.objects.get(id=self.first_person_id)` ). По этой же причине отдельно запущеный TestCase принимал использование id=1.

Вопрос решен, но буду благодарен за ссылку на объяснение данного феномена.